# What set of functions is considered when resolving overloaded functions assigning to default parameter values?

Tags: c++, overloading

Consider the function `bar` below, whose parameter has a default value initialized from an invocation of an overloaded `foo`:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int x)
{
  std::cout << "foo(int)" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

template<typename T>
void bar(T a, int x = foo(T(0))) {}

double foo(double x)
{
  std::cout << "foo(double)" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  bar<int>(1);
  bar<double>(1);
  return 0;
}
```

I expect this program to output

```
foo(int)
foo(double)
```

corresponding to `foo`'s two overloads which are visible at `bar`'s instantiation.

Instead, when compiled with `g++-4.6`, the output is

```
$ g++-4.6 -std=c++0x test.cpp; ./a.out 
foo(int)
foo(int)
```

Is the set of overloads considered when implementing a default parameter value different from normal overload resolution? Is this case described in the ISO C++ standard?

Comment: my output is `foo(int) foo(double)` on VS2012

Comment: clang++ (ToT build) on Linux agrees with Jared's output.

Comment: I believe it's UB because the default value is part of the declaration, and at that point the second overload isn't visible, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The same problem is exhibited by just calling `foo` inside the `bar`, and will say that there is no acceptable version of `foo` if you put `bar` above both definitions of `foo`. In g++ 4.7, it explicitly states that 'no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation'. Very surprising behavior; maybe a bug, but strange to see it in both clang and g++.

Comment: @Rollie: I think ADL does not apply to primitives such as `int` and `double` -- perhaps that explains this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what the standard says about this. First, in 8.3.6 [dcl.fct.default] paragraph 5:

> ... The names in the default argument are bound, and the semantic constraints are checked, at the point where the default argument appears. Name lookup and checking of semantic constraints for default arguments in function templates and in member functions of class templates are performed as described in 14.7.1. ...

Further in 14.7.1 [temp.inst] paragraph 12:

> If a function template f is called in a way that requires a default argument to be used, the dependent names are looked up, the semantics constraints are checked, and the instantiation of any template used in the default argument is done as if the default argument had been an initializer used in a function template specialization with the same scope, the same template parameters and the same access as that of the function template f
>   used at that point. This analysis is called default argument instantiation. The instantiated default argument is then used as the argument of f.

I'm not quite sure what this exactly says. I can see both interpretations in this text. In case it matters, I think EDG agrees with gcc and clang.

Answer (score 6):

This program suggests that the set of functions considered follows normal overload resolution rules:

```
#include <iostream>

struct type1 {};
struct type2 {};

int foo(type1 x)
{
  std::cout << "foo(type1)" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

template<typename T>
void bar(int x = foo(T())) {}

int foo(type2 x)
{
  std::cout << "foo(type2)" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  bar<type1>();
  bar<type2>();
  return 0;
}
```

When compiled with `g++-4.6`, this program outputs:

```
$ g++ test_2.cpp ; ./a.out 
foo(type1)
foo(type2)
```

In other words, `foo` is resolved via ADL when `bar` is instantiated.

The behavior for the code from the OP seems to be that ADL does not apply to primitives such as `int` and `double`, so the only overloads considered are those declared before `foo`'s call. The odd MSVC behavior seems to be non-standard.

Comment: Good catch. Is it specified in the standard that ADL only be applied for non primitive types? It seems counter-intuitive to me, but I'm sure there's a good reason.

Comment: `seems to be that ADL does not apply to primitives`, yep, from 3.4.2p2: `If T is a fundamental type, its associated sets of namespaces and classes are both empty.`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because you declared&defined the overloaded function "foo(double)" after the template, so it doesn't know anything about its existence . ->structured programming.
I'd suggest:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int x)
{
std::cout << "foo(int)" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

double foo(double x)
{
std::cout << "foo(double)" << std::endl;
return 0;
}

template<typename T>
void bar(T a, int x = foo(T(0))) {}



int main()
{
bar<int>(1);
bar<double>(1);
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I think this is the most probable reason, no rocket science